# Facebook App Invite error after upgrading from XCode 7.3.1 to XCode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on app in iOS. I have integrated Facebook App Invite, Everything works fine on XCode 7.3.1, After updating my app to XCode 8.1, Facebook App Invite is not working and getting this error:

app invite error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "(null)"

I have used this code to implement Facebook App Invite if user is already login with facebook

```
- (void)fb_fetch_after_login{
    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MYAPPLINKURL"];
    // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content
                                        delegate:self];
}
```

After this code execution , it gives error and call this delegate method

```
- (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [hud hide:YES];
    NSLog(@"app invite error:%@", error);
    NSString *message = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedDescriptionKey] ?:
    @"There was a problem sending the invite, please try again later.";
    NSString *title = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedTitleKey] ?: @"Oops!";
    
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

I have tried some solutions but did not work for me.  Anyone have this issue before on Xcode 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, and apparently it's a known bug. Take a look at their workaround while they fix it in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/984731934986423/

Comment: Thanks for your answer I also found this is facebook bug, Today it solved without changing any code...Thanks